# Does IIS 5.0 Require Unique Configuration Settings To Support UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, iis-5, windows-server-2000

[**Note**: I can only reproduce this issue with a Win2k web server running IIS 5.0. I can't reproduce this issue with a Windows XP web server (localhost) running IIS 5.1.]

I've uncovered a lot of information pertinent to UTF-8 encoding.

If I've learned one thing, it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856239/classic-asp-how-to-write-unicode-string-data-in-classic-asp/1856907#1856907).

**EDIT**: MSDN offered that for IIS 5.0 and earlier, [Response.CodePage is not available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525789(VS.90).aspx). At this time, I cannot verify that this is the root of my problem.

With all of that being said, here's my question:

> Does **IIS 5.0** Require Unique Configuration Settings To Support UTF-8?

Reason I ask: In spite of my best efforts to heed all of the advice from Google and SO, I still can't get UTF-8 characters to post to the server correctly.

Here's my scenario:

- Render UTF-8 encoded unicode strings to the screen. [Works fine, verified by visual inspection.]
- With javascript, store these UTF-8 encoded unicode strings in form variables. [Works fine, verified with Firebug.]
- Post to the same web page. [Special characters get corrupted on the server after the page has been posted.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, it doesn't require any unique settings outside of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856239/classic-asp-how-to-write-unicode-string-data-in-classic-asp/1856907#1856907).

**HOWEVER** - Beware of VBScript!!! [In my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087604/how-could-asp-server-side-code-corrupt-a-smart-quote/3111648#3111648), VBScript on IIS 5.0 mangled Unicode characters.

`Reponse.Write` is your friend. ;)