# Special Character Issue - Rails/DB2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, db2, special-characters

I have a Rails App and users are pasting certain values from MS Word.

When I pasted this...
Paul’s “Test2”

This is what gets rendered in the app...
Paulâ€™s â€œTestâ€

However, and this is the most bizarre aspect of this - this does not happen at once and I have not been able to track the specific circustances that leads to it.

So a couple of questions:

- given that this is happening, any
  suggestion on how to handle the
  rendering of this junk (I would try a
  simple gsub but am actually finding
  it difficult to see what the
  characters actually are that I'm
  trying to replace.)
- anyone seen anything like this? We're running Rails 2.3 and DB2 9.7

Thanks

Comment: Thanks glenn. yes, that's it. Specifically turns out our DB uses ISO-8859-1 encoding, but on the way out it's getting encoded into UTF-8, which causes the character sequence. Going to do a replace on the way in.

Answer (score 0):

These are MS Word "smart quotes".  See [How do I convert Word smart quotes and em dashes in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175785/how-do-i-convert-word-smart-quotes-and-em-dashes-in-a-string)